# Unity iOS build failed : Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, xcode6, photon

We are using Unity v5.3 and Xcode v6.3.

When we are trying to build for iOS, it throws error in build process:
"Apple Mach-O-Linker Error" - with tons of errors similar to this:

```
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
/Users/9tailstudios/Desktop/GoD_iOS/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(fmod_debug.o)
/Users/9tailstudios/Desktop/GoD_iOS/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(CctBoxController.o)
```

We have kept scripting backend as IL2CPP, target device as both iPhone and iPad, target SDK as Simulator SDK, target min iOS version as 7.0.

We are just using PUN for the multiplayer and JSONFx as a third party dll for handling JSON.

I don't have any experience in iOS development. So please, if anyone could help me in this.